# Connect socket.io from useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, socket.io, react-hooks

I want to connect my `socket` connection from `useEffect` like `componentDidMount`

```
const Chat = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);

  const socketRef = useRef(
    io('http://localhost:3002', {
      query: { token }
    })
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current.on('connected', msg => {
      console.log('connected');
      setUser(msg.user);
      setIsConnected(true);
      socketRef.current.on('message', message => {
        setMessages(messages => [...messages, message]);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  const inputChangeHandler = e => setInput(e.target.value);

  const sendMessage = () => {
    socketRef.current.emit('newMessage', `${user}: ${input}`);
    socketRef.current.on('messages', newMessages => setMessages(newMessages));
    setInput('');
  };

  if (!isConnected) {
    return <h1>Waiting for connection...</h1>;
  }
  return (
    <div className={cx('chat-container')}>
      <div className={cx('messages-container')}>
        <div className={cx('message-container')}>Greetings {user}!!!</div>
        {messages.map((message, index) => (
          <div className={cx('message-container')} key={index}>
            {message}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className={cx('inputs-container')}>
        <input
          className={cx('input')}
          value={input}
          onChange={e => inputChangeHandler(e)}
        />
        <button className={cx('send-button')} onClick={sendMessage}>
          Send
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

It should display "Waiting for connection..." and then when my code reaches the `useEffect` it should connect and then rerender my component with the content, but instead of that, I should refresh the page manually every time when I'm running the react server. After refreshing my code works exactly as I suppose.

It seems like it didn't receive the event in time.

Comment: What is the problem that you're running into? Does it display `Waiting for connection` forever, or..?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes it runs that message forever without connection, I should refresh the page to get the connection.

Comment: try put socketRef  in useEffect dependency. and put console.log in use effect to see when it is called

Comment: @Robert sorry it didn't worked :(

Comment: check  useEffect(() => {
   console.log(socketRef.current)....} what you have in this method when it is fired. you code look ok is weird behavior

Comment: You probably want to throw your `io()` call in the `useEffect()` too, you're opening a new socket connection every time `Chat` re-renders. Also why are you adding another listening to `messages` in `sendMessage`? And lastly you're not closing the connection anywhere. The `useEffect()` callback should return a function that closes the connection.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts so I need to define the ref and assign it in the useEffect? Also thank you for the advice, I added the disconnect in my effect and deleted the unnecessary second 'messages' event.

Comment: @Robert it prints the Socket object.